# IntelliJ IDEA Grails: Refresh the browser from the keyboard

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

When working on a Grails GSP page in IntelliJ IDEA, I would like to switch to the browser to check the changes. Is it possible to do this from within the IDE without touching the mouse?

Comment: Sorry, what's wrong with `Alt-Tab`, `F5`?

Comment: Or better yet, command+tab, F5. ;o)

Comment: too many keystrokes. Save: command+s, Flip to Browser: Alt+Tab, Refresh: command+R (or F5), see changes and hit Alt+Tab again. With the plugin and remote machine with the monitor next to you (or second monitor which is not my case), you just his commsnd+s and turn your head to see changes.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on Linux+Firefox:

- install this Firefox [plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/remote-control/)

  - right click on toolbar, select "Customize...", drag and drop icon "Remote control" to toolbar
  - enable remote control on tab you want the reload to happen by clicking the "Remote control icon"
- in IntelliJ go to "Settings/External tools", click Add button and fill the form:

> all checkboxes: uncheck
>   Name: **Firefox Refresh**
>
>   Command: **/bin/sh**
>
>   Parameters: **-c "echo reload | nc -c localhost 32000"**

- use "Settings/Keymap" to map keys to this external command

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut is not defined. Explanation Machine(OSX 10.10.4)

*Through Menu*

**Run > Reload in Browser**

*Through Keyboard Shortcuts*

**Preferences(⌘,) > Keymap > type in search field(reload in browser)>double click on "Reload in Browser"(Add Keyboard Shortcut)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use LiveEdit plugin for Idea
http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/08/liveedit-plugin-features-in-detail/

Its is possible to assign Idea hotkey to refresh browser